# Error in string find operation

Tags: c, c-strings, post-increment, double-pointer

Trying to find if PIR is present in the warning message and then take action, but I'm not understanding the behavior inside while statement...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *a="Intrusion detected PIR Sensor";//warning message
    char **p=&a,**x;
    char *b="PIR";//string check
    char *c=b;
    int count1=0,count2=0;
    while(*c++)//count the size of string 
        count1++;

    for( ;**p;p++)//check for the occurrence of string in warning msg
    {
        x=p;
        while((*b++)==(**x++))
            count2++;
    }
    if(count1==count2)
        printf("Success\n");
    else
        printf("Failure\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *c=&b;`...look there.......

Comment: sorry forgot to paste the recent version of code..

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm

Comment: Fyi, you never reset `b` after a failed iteration. Unless the first iteration is successful, `b` walks off the end of the search-for string and into the great void of *undefined behavior*. You should be using `c` and it should be reset on each iteration back to `c = &b`. That's just the first thing I noticed. I stopped looking after that.

Comment: You state that you do not understand the behviour inside the while loop. Which one? The `while(*c++) count1++;`or the `while((*b++)==(**x++))count2++;)`? I think you should ask about the setup of the for loop.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I recommend concentrating on what p is, what it points to and what it points to after being incremented. Don't forget the little brother x.

Comment: Incrementing `p` doesn't do what you think it does.  It gives you undefined behaviour on the second and subsequent iterations.  I'm not even sure I know what you think it is doing.

Comment: @Yunnosch I was pointing to second while loop.

Comment: I was trying to point to string using double pointer .then copy the address of the same pointer into another temporary pointer and then enter the second while loop and then check if both the strings are matching by comparing their derefenced values and if not matched increment the p pointer and point to second char of warning message.

Comment: p is pointer to pointer to char and gets initialised to point to a, which is a pointer to char; not wrong. `p++` (in the setup of for loop) increments p by size of pointer to char (say 4). I think it then points 4 bytes behind a. That seems strange to me. I think (without testing) that `(*p)++` would make more sense. That would increase what p is pointing to, i.e. a. It would make a point to the 'n' of "Intrusion". That would probably still not achieve the goal, but it would be less far off in non-guaranteed memory. That is why I recommend p as debugging target.